# Restricting same values in select dropdown in php not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have a select dropdown in php which comes from a database. If the value is already present in the column it should not display in select dropdown, so I have written the following code:

```
    <select class="form-control" id="space" name="space">
      <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
      <?php
      $select=mysqli_query($con,"select * from clients");
     while($menuz=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
      {
      $filled =$menuz['Space'];
     $valuez = array("C101","C102","C103","C104","C105","C106","C107","C108","W1","W2","W3","W4","W5","W6","W7","W8","W9","W10","W11","W12","F1","F2","F3","F4","F5","F6","F7","F8","F9","F10");
     foreach($valuez as $value){
        if($value != $filled){ 
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>">
          <?php echo $value;?>
        </option>
        <?php 
        }
     }
    }
    ?>
    </select>
```

This code was working fine till yesterday restricting values which are already in column. But today its not working. The following is the screenshot of the select dropdown and database:

[image]

[image]

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please var_dump($menuz['Space']) and upload it? I think array value will be output not string.

Comment: i didnt understand

Comment: want to know what is inside $menuz['Space'],can you write ar_dump($menuz['Space']) inside the code and show me the result?

Comment: where should i add this

Comment: you can edit the post

Comment: i mean where should i add this var_dump($menuz['Space']); which line

Comment: $filled =$menuz['Space'];
var_dump($filled);exit;

Comment: @スージン  its making my whole page not loading

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="space" name="space">
  <option value="--Select--">--Select--</option>
   <?php
     $select = mysqli_query($con,"select * from clients where Space NOT IN ('C101','C102','C103','C104','C105','C106','C107','C108','W1','W2','W3','W4','W5','W6','W7','W8','W9','W10','W11','W12','F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','F7','F8','F9','F10')");
     while($menu1=mysqli_fetch_array($select)) {
       $filled = $menu1['name'];
       if (!empty($filled)) {
   ?>
   <option value="<?php echo $filled;?>">
     <?php echo $filled;?>
   </option>
  <?php
    }}
  ?>
</select>
```

Your question is the same as this: [displaying values from sql in html select option not displaying values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59607510/displaying-values-from-sql-in-html-select-option-not-displaying-values/59608339#59608339)

Comment: this is not displaying any values in select dropwodn

Comment: Do you have value in the table clients except  'C101','C102','C103','C104','C105','C106','C107','C108','W1','W2','W3','W4','W5','W6','W7','W8','W9','W10','W11','W12','F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','F7','F8','F9','F10' ?

Comment: C101 is already on the list you want to skip, it is c101 (case-sensitive)?

Comment: Then your table client schema should be set to: DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 
COLLATE latin1_general_cs; This will help to search case sensitive values.

Comment: collation is latin_swedish_ci

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
while($menu1=mysqli_fetch_array($select))
 {
 $filled =$menu1['Space'];
 $valuez = array("C101","C102","C103","C104");
 foreach($valuez as $value){
    if($value != $filled){ 
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $value;?>">
          <?php echo $value;?>
        </option>
    <?php 
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: i didnt understand your code, what did you change in my code?